# Find button element with Selenium Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm very new to the Selenium module. i try to click the button "המשך" in this site https://www.jumbomail.me/he/  . this is my code:

```
import time,selenium
from selenium import webdriver

PATH =  r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chrome\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.jumbomail.me/he/')
input_fname=driver.find_element_by_id("tokenfield-tokenfield")
input_fname.send_keys('nareom@reg-ujmv.com')
input_fname = driver.find_element_by_class_name("send-button jm-button ng-binding ng- scope")
```

this is the HTML code in the webpage:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="vm.submit(false)" class="send-button jm-button ng- 
binding ng-scope" ga-click-event="['Send Form', 'Click', 'Next - Submit button']" 
data-uw-styling-context="true">                        המשך                    
</button>
```

when i run it, i get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable 
to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".send-button jm-button ng- 
binding ng-scope"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

direct click with `implicit` or `Explicit wait` does not work, it needs a `JS` intervention.

**Full code :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH =  r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chrome\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.jumbomail.me/he/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='סגירה']"))).click()
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[ng-click='vm.submit(false)']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `wait` to let the elements loaded before accessing them.
Also the submit button המשך can be uniquely located with `button` tag name and `send-button` class name while other class names there are not unique and may dynamically change.

```py
import time,selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH =  r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chrome\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://www.jumbomail.me/he/')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tokenfield-tokenfield"))).send_keys('nareom@reg-ujmv.com')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.send-button"))).send_keys('nareom@reg-ujmv.com').click()
```